# Microsoft Bot Framework State Management

Tags: c#, azure, botframework

we are updating our MBF bot to have its state managed in Azure Table Store. We changed code according to documentation to register our Table store provider:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        var store = new TableBotDataStore("...");

        builder.Register(c => store)
            .Keyed<IBotDataStore<BotData>>(AzureModule.Key_DataStore)
            .AsSelf()
            .SingleInstance();

        builder.Register(c => new CachingBotDataStore(store,
                CachingBotDataStoreConsistencyPolicy
                .ETagBasedConsistency))
                .As<IBotDataStore<BotData>>()
                .AsSelf()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;

        var container = builder.Build();
        config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
}
```

Now, in the dialog we use following to store and load user data:

```
context.PrivateConversationData.SetValue<UserData>(UserDataRepositoryKey, userData);
```

Interesting thing is that dialog state seems to be maintained, but we see nothing is our Azure table and I really doubt any calls are getting to that storage. The documentation is super unclear on how to use state in the right way.

Question:

1. Does our container registration looks correct? Should it be at the app_start or should we register it for every request?
2. Are we using right method to store state during the conversation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you are not updating the `Conversation` container. You need to use the `Conversation.UpdateContainer` method for that.

```
Conversation.UpdateContainer(
           builder =>
           {
               builder.Register(c => store)
                         .Keyed<IBotDataStore<BotData>>(AzureModule.Key_DataStore)
                         .AsSelf()
                         .SingleInstance();

               builder.Register(c => new CachingBotDataStore(store,
                          CachingBotDataStoreConsistencyPolicy
                          .ETagBasedConsistency))
                          .As<IBotDataStore<BotData>>()
                          .AsSelf()
                          .InstancePerLifetimeScope();


           });
```

Docs around the topic can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state-azure-table-storage and a sample at https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/AzureTable.